# Does $\{ 0, \{ 0 \} \}$ contradict the axiom of regularity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms, natural-numbers

I'm trying to understand the ZFC axioms, and I understand most of them except the axiom of regularity.

$$\forall x[\exists a(a\in x) \Rightarrow \exists y(y\in x \wedge \neg\exists z(z\in y \wedge z\in x))]$$

From what I understand, it is saying that, for all non-empty sets that have a set for an element, the set does not share any elements with the original set and the element of the set. However, wouldn't that make the natural number construction of 2 impossible because:

$$2 = \{ 0, 1 \} = \{ 0, \{ 0 \} \}$$

If we choose $x = 2$ and we choose the element $\{ 0 \}$ to be our $y$. There does exist an element $z$ which is in both sets, more precisely $0$.
$$0 \in 2 \, \land \, 0 \in \{ 0 \}$$
What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make a ridiculous version of your mistake.

**"Theorem".** All sets are empty.

*"Proof".* Let $A$ be a set, if it is not empty, then there is a subset of $A$ which is not empty as well. Consider $\varnothing$ as a subset of $A$. It is empty, therefore $A$ is empty. $\square$

When we say $\exists y$, we are not asking you to choose one $y$ and test it against the formula. We are asking you to go through *all* possible $y$'s until you find one that matches, and only when you've exhausted all of the possible $y$'s, you can say that this is false.

In the case of $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$, setting $y=\{\varnothing\}$ is not enough. You also need to test $\varnothing$ itself. Which, of course, is a suitable witness.

(Since we use the term "witness", let me make a real-life metaphor to your situation. There had been a crime, and you're asking for witnesses. You choose one carefully selected old person who is deaf, blind, mute, and wasn't in the area at the time of the alleged crime. Asking them if they saw anything, they tell you that they didn't. You conclude that there are no witnesses to corroborate the crime.)

Comment: Right, I understand. Is it because this statement is true for at least one element so this follows the axiom correctly. Is the only possible way to break this axiom, is if the set is equal to a set containing itself?

Comment: Are there any ways to break this axiom?

Comment: Well, if you assume hat it false. We have a family of "anti-foundation axioms" (since regularity is also known as foundation) which imply that the axiom is false in very specific ways.

Comment: @JoshuaPasa A simple situation that would make the axiom false would be if we had a set that is an element of itself, i.e. a set $x$ such that $x\in x.$ Or perhaps more simple: a set $x$ that is its only element, i.e. $x=\{x\}.$  $\sf ZF$ proves no set with this property exists since it would contradict regularity, but such sets can typically be proven to exist in set theories with antifoundation axioms.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Wouldn't the Zermelo ordinals break this axiom if you assume an infinite set: $\omega = \{ \{ \{...\} \} \}$. since it is infinite, the set containing its self would be the set its self

Comment: @JoshuaPasa There is no such thing as the Zermelo ordinals (as opposed to the Zermelo naturals) for precisely this reason. No natural way to represent $\omega$ and continue into the transfintite. You are right... the first thing you'd try would be non-well-founded.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: I'm not sure why "the first thing you'd try" should be an infinitely nested set. The von Neumann ordinal $ω$ is not some 'infinite' application of the successor map either. Rather, it is the union of all the smaller ones. Similarly, one can very well define the Zermelo ordinals as the closure of the empty set under $(x ↦ \{x\})$ and union of any set of them. It wouldn't violate regularity either.

Comment: @user21820 Yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 6):

In the axiom of regularity, the variable $y$ is bound by an existential quantifier, not a universal quantifier.  So it won't necessarily work for just any element $y\in x$; rather, there is *some* element of $x$ that works.  In your example, $y=1$ does not work, but $y=0$ does work.

Comment: I don't understand why choosing y = 1 is a mistake. The element 1 is itself a set with elements in it, isn't that one of the requirements for the axiom?

Comment: @JoshuaPasa $y=1$ doesn't work, but that doesn't mean that *no* choice of $y$ works; the axiom of regularity says that *some* choice of $y$, not *every* choice of $y$, will do the job.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I understand, thanks. It was my misunderstanding of the exists quantifier